# How to download a text editor on xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, text, editor

Should I install my text editor from the ubuntu software store or download it manually? And how do I download it manually?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which release you're using, nor which text editor you actually want; however Xubuntu comes with `mousepad` which is the Xfce text editor already (it's pretty good & the most efficient resource wise for use with the Xfce desktop as it uses libs already in memory as used by the desktop)..  If you wanted to install `mousepad` via command, it would be `sudo apt install mousepad`.  Since `mousepad` isn't available as *snap*, I'll use `gedit` as example, but to install a snap it's `snap install gedit` (`gedit` is available in *deb* format too so you can `apt install gedit`)

Comment: Geany is a good text editor, that you can install with `sudo apt install geany`from the repository universe.